# Creating a table that records a time series SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, join, time-series, union

I am a novice in SQL and I am trying to write a query that will allow me to create a time series table. I have a table in a data warehouse that I am pulling into tableau (simplified table image attached). This table updates daily. What I want to do is create a query that takes a snapshot of this table at the end of each month and adds it to the new table I am creating with my custom query. This way as the months go by I will be able to see the change in entries from month to month, and the table will gain more entries as time goes on (not update day to day). Is there any way I could do this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

I tried to create my own date column using the using the ADD COLUMN command but the date updates by the day.
Not sure how I can create a time series table with an as of date for the 12 Months. Could I possibly join in or union the table with itself each month?

Comment: Hi - please don't use images, only editable text so that someone can copy it if they need to. Please also update your quest with an example of what you are trying to achieve (based on the sample data you've provided)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create a summary by month and year.
Let's assume that you are trying to see active and inactive by month.
You can create a view to summarize the data as follows and use it in any reporting tool.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_active_inactive
AS
SELECT YEAR(hire_date) year, MONTH(hire_date) month, SUM(IIF(active_status='Y',1,0)) active, SUM(IIF(active_status='N',1,0)) inactive
FROM  tab1
GROUP BY YEAR(hire_date),  MONTH(hire_date)

select * from vw_active_inactive
```